# calling setResult from Service class

Tags: android, service, fragment, onactivityresult

In my `UiFragment` frgament I have where I try to connect with my device.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE:
                    // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        connectDevice(data);
                    }
                    break;
            }
    }
```

and I also have `StartScanService` class where I need to do something similar to `setResult` (as I do that in Activity class)

```
public class StartScanService extends Service {
 ...
 ...
private void connect(String tmp){
        adapter.cancelDiscovery();

        String address = tmp.substring(tmp.length() - 17);

        // Create the result Intent and include the MAC address
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, address);

        // Set result 
        //setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);

    }
```

}

So I need to call fragment class method from service class. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do that using interface. First I create interface

```
public interface ServiceCallBack {
    void connectToDevice(Intent intent);
}
```

and in my Service class I call interface method 'connectToDevice'

```
public class StartScanService extends Service {
...
...
...
private ServiceCallBack serviceCallBack;

private void connect(String tmp){
        adapter.cancelDiscovery();

        String address = tmp.substring(tmp.length() - 17);

        // Create the result Intent and include the MAC address
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, address);

        if (serviceCallBack != null) {
            serviceCallBack.connectToDevice(intent);
        }
    }
```

}

My Fragment  class must implements ServiceCallBack interface

```
public class UiFragment extends Fragment implements ServiceCallBack{
private ServiceConnection connectionService = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        Log.d(TAG + " VEG", "onServiceConnected");
        StartScanService.ScanBinder scan = (StartScanService.ScanBinder) service;
        startScanService = scan.getScanService();
        startScanService.setHandler(handler);
        startScanService.setServiceCallBack(UiFragment.this);
        startScanService.startScan();
        bound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        bound = false;
        Log.d(TAG, "onServiceDisconnected");
    }
};

@Override
public void connectToDevice(Intent intent) {
    connectDevice(intent);
}
}
```